# Can't update fields in jira-python

Tags: python, jira

Unable to update fields for an issue in Jira-python.  I can read the fields fine, but don't see them updated.  Example:

```
issue.update(fields={'description':'a comment'})
```

Have also tried:

```
issue.update({'description':'a comment'})
```

and 100 other things, other fields, both custom and standard.

If I try to read back my changes immediately with:

```
 issue.fields.description
```

it doesn't show any change.
There are no error messages, and no return codes.  I have proper administrative privileges, etc.  Any clues appreciated.

Comment: From http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ I'd expect this to work: issue.update(description='Changed the summary to be different.') so try that and then check the value in the browser. Sometimes you need to refresh the issue data with something like:  issue = jira.issue(issue.key, expand='comments')

Comment: I was able to intercept the return code within the 'requests' package.  It indicates:  (including your sample code above)  Error 400: Bad Request. "one of 'fields' or 'update' required".  This doesn't make sense to me because there is no 'update' field, and 'fields' is NOT required.  Even if I put 'fields' in, as I show in the original text, I get the same message.  Another user is writing to jira directly (using a different tool, and is having no problem).

Comment: I could get this to work by changing the key in line 123 of resources.py from 'body' to 'fields'.  But I don't know if that counts as a bug in the code, or just a quirk in our installation of Jira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
issue.update(description="ASFASFASD")
```

According to the documentation, it should works. https://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/